# Permission denied when su as other user

Tags: ubuntu

While logged in as root I run:

```
su username screen
```

I get permission denied.

But when I logged in as username I am allowed to do screen.

**I can**, however, run:

```
sudo -u username screen
```

My goal is to run a Java application with a limited user for security reasons.
Maybe I have already achieved this goal by running the way it works, you tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `su` to run commands as another user, then the correct syntax is

```
su - username -c screen
```

That will simulate the login of the user and the `-c` will  pass the command `screen` to the shell of the user.

To verify this, run the following command as `root`

```
su -l username ls
```

The output will be a listing of the contents of username's home directory no matter what the current working directory is as it will have simulated the login of username and then run `ls` on its home.

Of course, the less complex method is with the second command that you used:

```
sudo -u username screen
```

The syntax:

```
sudo -u username <command>
```

simply runs the command as the specified user. You can see this by running the command as `root` in `/root`:

```
sudo -u username ls
```

It will return `permission denied` as only `root` and the group `root` have access to that directory. In any event, either of the commands that I've mentioned will do what you want.

Comment: So basically the two methods achieve the same?
Is one method more secure than the other?

Comment: Well, I get from this that no. []https://www.makeuseof.com/sudo-vs-su/#:~:text=Because%20sudo%20is%20granular%20and,set%20up%20to%20use%20sudo.

Comment: @PaulSirota Using `su -` by itself opens a root shell as the `-` grants the environment of root which is what the link is getting at. In the case above, the command is `su - username -c`. What that does is to simulate a login of the user which can be seen by the fact that the user will `username` afterwards if you do it that way. Adding `-c command` runs the command as the user and not as root. In this case, that is the same as running `sudo -u username <command>`.